# Escape from nested try - catch statement

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I am currently debugging code with nested try-catch statements.

I can easily handle the errors with the `dbstop` command, but each time I look at the code and want to stop running the program, I have to enter `dbquit` once for each nesting level.

As this is quite annoying I am looking for a solution to really stop debugging all programs once I am done debugging.

Here is an example of how I call the code:

```
dbstop if error
dbstop if caught error
mytestmain
```

And here is an example of what the function could look like (the subfunction may or may not be in a different .m file)

```
function mytestmain 
try
    mytestsub
catch
end

%% Definition of subfunction
function mytestsub
try
    a=b;%generate an error as b is not defined
catch
end
```

---

What have I tried?

- I tried using a script or a function that calls `dbquit` twice, however this will only execute `dbquit` once.
- I tried using `dbquit('all')`, but with no effect

---

Note that I prefer not to remove the try-catch statements in the code.

Comment: This behavior is surprising; `dbquit` should get you all the way out of the debugger and code execution, regardless of how deeply nested your try/catches are. I do it often with deeply nested try/catches. What version of Matlab are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `dbclear` before using `dbquit`

```
dbclear all; dbquit;
```

Note, however, that this will also clear all breakpoints you set manually, hence, if you use breakpoints in addition, you should rather use

```
dbclear if error; dbclear if caught error; dbquit;
```

Comment: Except that might be more annoying if you *also* use breakpoints...plus, you have to re-type the `dbstop if caught error; dbstop if error` all the time...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Yes, you are right; thanks for noting that. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Actually I would work around this by having one shortcut with `dbclear if error; dbclear if caught error; dbquit;` and a second one with `dbstop if caught error;dbstop if error;` Then it's just two clicks.

Comment: I suppose I will go for the 2 step solution, though I still don't understand why it is not possible to combine these steps into 1.

Comment: Probably the same reason why `dbquit` does not work in a while loop, which is also a mystery to me.

Comment: Lets see whether we can find out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940495/difference-between-script-and-matlab-command-window

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how it's supposed to work. A single `dbquit` should get you completely out of the debugger regardless of how deeply nested your try/catch statements are and what breakpoints are still set.

Are you running an old version of Matlab? There's a [known bug related to `dbstop if caught error`](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/519233) in pre-R2009b versions of Matlab that sounds like it could cause this behavior. You could upgrade if you're on an older version.

Regardless of your version, try doing `dbstop if all error` instead of separate `dbstop if error` and `dbstop if caught error` statements and see if the behavior changes.

I would have also guessed maybe you're running multiple functions from within the "K>>" prompt and ending up with nested debugger sessions, but the `dbquit('all')` you did should have taken care of that case.

Comment: The version I use is quite recent, and I don't think thats the problem. My guess is indeed also something like nested sessions, or that I first catch an error (caught by the `dbstop if caught error`) and then actually create an error by using `dbquit` which then triggers the `dbstop if error` condition. I will try your solution when I have the chance.