# Difference between script and matlab command window

Tags: matlab, command-line

I wonder what the difference is between entering a few lines in the command window, or letting a script execute them.

In  the question [Escape from nested try - catch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938374/escape-from-nested-try-catch-statement) I have an example function. I have put the selected code in a script and *called it*, however then it does not work properly. On the other hand, when I 
*select the lines and hit f9*, it works as expected.

The lines are:

```
dbclear all
dbquit
dbstop if caught error
```

I call the example function as such:

```
dbstop if caught error
mytestmain
```

And the example function is:

```
function mytestmain 
try
    mytestsub
catch
end

% Definition of subfunction, may or may not be in the same .m file
function mytestsub
try
    a=b; %Intentionally generate an error as b is not defined
catch
end
```

Comment: When you say "does not work properly" and "works as expected", what specifically is happening, and what behavior do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's related to MATLAB's [just-in-time (JIT) compiler](http://books.google.at/books?id=63T7XpfMH38C&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq=matlab%20just%20in%20time%20compiler&source=bl&ots=-Z-hS-dOJw&sig=TBoCgJRiIJx8w05HVW3-_NQ2EpE&hl=de&sa=X&ei=nzivUZTXN4fTPNaLgJgI&ved=0CFgQ6AEwBzgK#v=onepage&q=matlab%20just%20in%20time%20compiler&f=false), which compiles functions before it runs them.

It seems that it compiles functions differently if `dbstop` is set or not (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7651) for reference). As it currently stands, MATLAB can not recompile a function while it is run (just try saving a changed function during a `dbstop`, and you will get a message informing you). As you can add and remove breakpoints during a `dbstop` I think you can also do so programmatically, but it should be impossible to "turn on" debugging if it wasn't turned on at "compile time"

So in your cases:

- Using `F9` it's just pasted and parsed as if you input it manually. So first `dbstop` is set, then `mytestmain` gets compiled and executed.
- Running as a script will first compile the script and `mytestmain` and then execute it - so `dbstop` would be set after compilation and therefore not in effect.

Comment: I suppose it could be a compilation issue, but I do notice that it also occurs with `feature accel off`.

Comment: I also found info about this command. But it seems to be missing in my matlab version (2012b) - how did you turn it off?

Comment: I have found it here, not sure if it actually still works though: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function/

Comment: oh interesting. the `IsDebug` and `JIT` options look interesting as well. Also did you clear your memory in between - my be Matlab cached the old compiled version.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "doesn't work", it could just be because the debugger is a special context and certain debugger commands - `dbup`, `dbdown`, and `dbquit` - only work when you're at a debugger "K>>" prompt. Once you call a script, you're no longer at the debugger prompt but in normal code execution - inside a nested M-code call stack - and they just don't work there. When you F9, it does the lines individually, so each one is done from the prompt.

As a workaround, if you really want to execute a sequence of debugger commands like this, you could write a little Java Swing widget to enter the text in to the command window just as though you were typing it in.

Comment: I can imagine that the commands (second `dbquit` and further) go to the wrong prompt. However, in that case I would expect the notification that dbquit is only allowed in debug mode. Now simply nothing happens.