# Axis equal fail matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have an interesting problem in matlab. If i run the following code in a script and i run it by selecting it and pressing F9:

```
figure
subplot(4, 4, [1 2 5 6 9 10]);
plotGrid(spin1HGD, 2);    % A function to plot a grid, 
                          % essentially a bunch of patches. 
campos([27.8504  -39.0203   71.3373]);
axis equal
```

I get the following figure:

[image]

now if i immediately run `axis equal`, it actually does it:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my matlab terminal:

[image]

So i am definitely running `axis equal` at the end of the script and then I am having to actually manually run it for it to work.

Annoyingly, I cant reproduce it in anything but this code? What is the deal?

Comment: Try it with `plot` instead of `subplot`?

Comment: Interesting problem, does it still happen when you put `pause(1)` above the axis command? Also... Could you try to post runnable code because without having `spin1HGD` and `plotGrid` the code will not run. Furthermore, a problem that is not the same but may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940495/difference-between-script-and-matlab-command-window

Comment: Have you tried a ``drawnow`` before the ``axis equal``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, adding `drawnow` before `axis equal` will fix this problem.

To reproduce the issue, run this code in a script:

```
figure
subplot(4, 4, [1 2 5 6 9 10]);
patch(rand(3), rand(3), [1 0 1])
campos([27.8504  -39.0203   71.3373]);
% drawnow 
axis equal
```

then type 'axis equal' in the command window and notice that the plot changes.